# How to translate address labels in partner form in Odoo 14?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-14, poedit

In Odoo 14, the `res.partner` form view has the following code to set a label for the address `div`:

```
<span class="o_form_label o_td_label" name="address_name">
    <b attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('type', '!=', 'contact')]}">Company Address</b>
    <b attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('type', '!=', 'invoice')]}">Invoice Address</b>
    <b attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('type', '!=', 'delivery')]}">Delivery Address</b>
    <b attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('type', '!=', 'other')]}">Other Address</b>
    <b attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('type', '!=', 'private')]}">Private Address</b>
    <b attrs="{'invisible': ['&amp;', ('parent_id', '!=', False), ('type', '!=', False)]}">Address</b>
</span>
```

None of those labels are translated to any language. I am trying to do it but there are not recognized by Odoo, even when I try to force the translation file to do it.

Has anyone tried to translate them? If so, what did you do exactly?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.